# Can't perform else if array is nil

Tags: objective-c

I created a method to search for people in an address book, and I want to return the result as an array, and if there are result to print them out, else to print "Not found".

From some reason I can print the result if the array is not nil, but the else is not working...it's not even giving me eror, this is the code:

main.m

```
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        result = [myBook searchName:@"jack"];

        if (result != nil){
            for (AddressCards *nextCard in result)
            NSLog(@"%@          %@", nextCard.name, nextCard.email);
        }

        else
            NSLog(@"Not found");
```

AdressBook.m

```
-(NSMutableArray *) searchName:(NSString *) someName{

    NSMutableArray *namsFound = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (AddressCards *addressCard in book){

        if ([addressCard.name rangeOfString:someName options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            [namsFound addObject:addressCard];
    }

    return namsFound;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: NSPredicate would be a better way to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `searchName:` method never returns nil. It returns an empty array sometimes, but that's not the same thing.

You might do something like this in `searchName:`:

`return [namsFound count]? namsFound : nil;`

This will return namsFound iff namsFound has 1 or more elements (in other words, if some names are found). Otherwise, it will return nil.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way to do it. And after doing this, you can just use `if (result) {...` in your main.m.

Answer (score 0):

If you change this:

```
if (result != nil){
```

To this, it should work:

```
if (result.count) {
```

You are always returning a non-nil pointer, since you always alloc/init the array in the search method.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `if (result != nil){`, use `if (result.count > 0){`

Answer (score 0):

It does not print `"Not found"` because it is never not `nil`.  Results are always `!= nil` because even in the case of not having found the search name, it will return an array - an unpopulated array, that is one with zero elements. `if (result.count){` is the most elegant solution IMO because `0` is equivalent to boolean `false`, so a `result.count` that returns `0` will go straight to `else`.